# Processing hundreds of thousands of records using Hibernate and Threading, swiftly

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have a serious problem. I'm working on a code that should process over 500,000 records in an hour. Typically, each of these records has data in another table, which I have to go and look for while processing.

I am currently using hibernate. I tried using an Executor service with multiple threads to handle 100 records each - so that's, 10 threads, each processing a 100 record, and when a thread is done, it leaves the pool and another thread enters.

But the thing is, speed hasn't improved. I noticed, the more threads I run, the slower the whole process. Currently, it takes 2 mins for a thread to process 100 of these records. When I have 10 threads running, it takes 20 mins, which is essentially the same as running a thousand records in 1 thread!

I thought these threads were supposed to run concurrently. Is there a differently implementation I can utilise?

Mind you, I'm using a server that has 8 cores and 64GIG RAM.

Thanks

Comment: So your bottleneck is perhaps somewhere else. Think about disk / network IO, database locks (transaction mgmt.), semaphores in your Java code (synchronized blocks and so on). I'd start with a detailied analysis...

Comment: "I thought these threads were supposed to run concurrently" - what makes you think they are not?

Comment: because, when I run one thread it takes about 2 mins to complete processing for 100 records. When I run 10 threads, with 1 processing 100 records, it takes about 20 minutes. That doesn't sound like it's concurrent to me

Comment: Some log statements should easily clear that up - a log statement when the run method starts and one when it ends. If the messages are interleaved, then you have concurrent execution, if not then you don't. Using an Executor with multiple threads does not guarantee faster execution, it guarantees concurrent execution. It's quite possible that you have a DB locking issue (as 'home' suggested) and the use of multiple threads is exacerbating the issue, rather than improving it.

Comment: I have log statements, and yes, in that case, it is concurrent. However, how come it takes longer for all of them to finish, than it does with just one? I'm trying to improve their performance. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you ever used a tool like JVisualVM? It can tell you which of your methods is taking the lion's share of the run time and give you an idea where your bottleneck is. It's bundled with the JDK. TBH, if your code is trying to process large datasets and performance degrades with multiple threads, that suggests to me that you have (i) poor SQL, (ii) badly-thought-out transactions or something.

Comment: Hi Ramsay, you're right. I actually took a second look at my queries and table structure and decided to carry out a redesign and everything's working fine now. Could you post an answer so I can mark it as correct to close this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by querying the hibernate entities in their lightest form. Rather than querying lists of entire objects with all variables, I queried lists of entire objects with just their ids, sent them to the threads, and then queried each object according to the specific columns I needed.

That sped up the process. Most of my tables have a lot of columns, most of which I don't need in my processing.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd run the app under a profile such as Jprofiler and see where the processing gets stuck. You'll know what's the problem in 30 minutes.